# React push Api response in the setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my EventForm i have this const, this is a dialog form

this is my EventForm.js

```
const EventForm = (props) => {

const { setOpenPopup, records, setRecords, setMessage, setOpenSnackbar } = props

const addEvent = () => {
    axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/events', (event)
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data)
        const newData = [{
          title: resp.data.name,
          start: resp.data.starts_at,
          end:  resp.data.ends_at
        }]
        setRecords([{ ...records, newData}])
        //
        setOpenPopup(false)
        setMessage('New Event added')
        setOpenSnackbar(true)
      })
      .catch([])
  }



export default EventForm
EventForm.propTypes = {
  setOpenPopup: PropTypes.func,
  records: PropTypes.array,
  setRecords: PropTypes.func,
  setMessage: PropTypes.func,
  setOpenSnackbar: PropTypes.func
}

}
```

in my EventTable.js

```
 const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/events')
  .then(resp => {
    const newData = resp.data.map((item) => ({
      title: item.name,
      start: item.starts_at,
      end:  item.ends_at
    }))
    setRecords(newData)
  })
  .catch(resp => console.log(resp))
  }, [])



fullcalendar...
 events={records}
```

im trying to push the API post response to my setRecords. so when the dialog form close it will not use the GET response. ill just get the new record and render to my view

but im getting an error:

> Unhanded Rejection (TypeError): setRecords is not a function

[image]

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. The error mentions `SetRecord` which is nowhere to be seen in the code you've provided here.

Comment: i set the setRecords in the const?

Comment: @DeezNuuts no the error you mentioned says `setRecord`, the one you destructure is `setRecords`, with an "s" at the end. Also, that `setRecords` definition isn't included in the question, are you sure it's a function and what you think it is?

Comment: @Jayce444 im not sure. im using React currently for 2days let me update my question

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using React Hooks. Make sure that your `records` state looks like this

```js
const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);
```

In your `axios` request, it looks like that you are trying to spread the values of records which is an array to an object. I'd suggest refactoring this to something like this. Instead of trying to spread an array into the object, take the previous state and merge it with the new one.

```js
setRecords(prevRecords => [...prevRecords, ...newData])
```

Here's an example using React Hooks how the component could look like

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const MyComponent = ({
  setOpenPopup,
  records,
  setRecords,
  setMessage,
  setOpenSnackbar
}) => {
  const addEvent = () => {
    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/events", event) // Make sure this is defined somewhere
      .then((resp) => {
        const { name, starts_at, ends_at } = resp.data;
        const newData = [
          {
            title: name,
            start: starts_at,
            end: ends_at
          }
        ];

        setRecords((prevRecords) => [...prevRecords, ...newData]);
        setOpenPopup(false);
        setMessage("New Event added");
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
      })
      .catch([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addEvent}>Click me </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

If you are not using React Hooks and use Class components, then make sure that you pass `setRecords` to your component in props. Plus, in your props destructuring, make sure you add `this` to the props, otherwise, it can lead to unwanted behaviour. Also, move your request function out of the `render` method and destructure values from the props that you need inside the function. I've also noticed that your `axios` syntax was incorrect (forgot to close after the event) so I fixed that as well. Here's an example of how you can improve it.

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  addEvent = () => {
    const {
      setOpenPopup,
      setRecords,
      setMessage,
      setOpenSnackbar
    } = this.props;

    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/events", event)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        const newData = [
          {
            title: resp.data.name,
            start: resp.data.starts_at,
            end: resp.data.ends_at
          }
        ];
        setRecords((prevRecords) => [...prevRecords, ...newData]);
        //
        setOpenPopup(false);
        setMessage("New Event added");
        setOpenSnackbar(true);
      })
      .catch([]);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.addEvent()}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: i will separate the  records, setRecords in the props? am i right?

Comment: I've added an example with the Class components.

Comment: i update my question with some information

Comment: Check the example of React Class component that I put.

Comment: im not using class components

Comment: i follow the setRecords((prevRecords) => [...prevRecords, ...newData]); got the same error

Comment: I've added an example with React Hooks as well.

Comment: i follow that also same error. i think. something wrong in my idea. the goal is when the dialog form close and had status code 200 get that record and push in the existing Array in the view. i think i will focus more in the dialog when closing?

Comment: If you can, add your code to something like `codesandbox.io` and share it here so I can see what's going wrong.